# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound raises 404 instead of 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We had an action that was essentially failing silently in production because it was raising an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, which Rails treats as a 404 error instead of a 500 error- meaning it wasn't being captured by our error logger.

I don't like that Rails maps certain errors to 404s- I think it should be up to the developer to decide whether a URL is invalid, or whether the failure to retrieve an record is an application error.

How do we ensure all Rails errors are treated as 500 errors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, if you can manually notify your error logger of the error, that would probably be the best thing to do. Making Rails return a different HTTP status code might break other parts of your application.

However, if you absolutely must do so, you can instruct Rails not to return a 404 by removing the corresponding entry from the rescue responses hash. You could do this in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/rescue_responses_overrides.rb
ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses
  .delete('ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound')
```

Now Rails will send a 500 status code to the browser whenever `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is raised. You could also remove all entries in a single step:

```
ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses.clear
```

To see which other errors Rails returns different status codes for, you can simply print the hash in the Rails console:

```
pp ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses
```

Answer (score 12):

> it was raising an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error, which Rails treats as a 404 error instead of a 500 error

It's the right thing to do. Imagine a search crawler hitting your blog app and getting an error on your non-existing blog post. If you return `500`, the crawler will try to visit the page again later. If you return `404`, the crawler will recognize the page is missing and will probably stop trying. Some browsers even display custom built-in page if the server responds with `500`.

If you still want to proceed, you have a few options. You can [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) in your top controller and change the response to whatever you want.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, OtherError do |exception|
    render nothing: true, status: 500 # nothing, redirect or a template
  end
end
```

One other option is to use a custom [`exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration). It's basically a rack app that gets invoked when an exception occurs and you can do anything you want with the request/response. You can take a look at the default implementation ([`ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/41231ef6c6c6a6e546b69add28f04aafb9e0e952/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb#L12)) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks- disagree that it's right thing to do though, as it assumes RecordNotFound == URL not found. RecordNotFound could result from some internal logic error on a perfectly good URL, as was the case in our situation.

Comment: @Yarin Well, in an ideal world the internal logic error should never bubble up unhandled to the web layer but I see your point.

Comment: I agree with @JiříPospíšil -- it's the right thing to do. Rails is REST-oriented architecture. Failing to find a record (resource) should map to a 404. If you need that to be recorded in the logger, you can add additional `Rails.logger.*` calls into your controller actions.

40x = "You messed up" (ie. you looked for something that isn't there)
50x = "We messed up" (ie. you gave a good request but we munged the processing somehow)

Comment: In Rails 7, `nothing: true` should be replaced with `body: nil`